# Поиск минимума функции с scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Прошу помочь с исправлением ошибки. Код оптимизации следующий:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds, minimize
m = 20
n = 10
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.randn(m, n)
y = np.random.randn(m)
bounds = Bounds(np.zeros([n]), np.ones([n]))
def f_1(theta):
    return (np.dot(X,theta) - y)**2
theta = np.random.randn(n)
x0 = np.random.randn(n)
minimize(f_1, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args, f0)
    699             try:
--> 700                 df = df.item()
    701             except (ValueError, AttributeError):

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args, f0)
    700                 df = df.item()
    701             except (ValueError, AttributeError):
--> 702                 raise ValueError("The user-provided "
    703                                  "objective function must "
    704                                  "return a scalar value.")

ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value.
```

Не понимаю, что именно не нравится интерпретатору?

Comment: Обновил в задании

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) неявно указаны требования к минимизируемой функции:

> fun: callable
>
> The objective function to be minimized.
>
> ```
>  fun(x, *args) -> float
> ```
>
> `NOTE: --------> ^^^^^^^^`  !!!!!
>
> where `x` is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and `args` is a tuple of the
> fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function.

Т.е. функция должна возвращать скалярное значение типа `float` или скаляр такого типа, который может быть преобразован к `float`.

Comment: Можете конкретно в коде указать, где ошибка? Для более быстрого понимания

Comment: @Scouser57, в функции `f_1()`, которая возвращает __нескалярное__ значение

Comment: спасибо, получилось!